# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and ((1,))

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple function using python, numpy and matplotlib but when I execute the script it returns a ValueError described in the title.

This is my code:

```
"""Geometrical interpretation: In Python, plot the function y = f(x) = x**3 − (1/x)
and plot its tangent line at x = 1 and at x = 2."""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot(func):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
    plt.plot(x, func, '-', color='pink')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


plot(lambda x: x ** 3 - (1 / x))
```

Please send this beginer some help :)

Comment: show the **real** error message in the question (formatted, and un-edited).

Comment: That was the error copied and pasted

Comment: OK. show the error message in the question (formatted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a good effort actually. You only needed to add the y variable using `y=func(x)`. And then `plt.plot(x,y)`...

so this works:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot(func):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
    y = func(x)
    plt.plot(x, y, '-', color='pink')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


plot(lambda x: x ** 3 - (1 / x))
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it did work. I'm just waiting to mark as solved. Could you explain why that solves this issue?

Comment: Yes,  you correctly passed in the lambda as `func`,  but you did not use it.   the plot needs a series of x and y values....  so if you do `print(y)` you will see the `y` values...

Comment: Oh. I understood it. Again, thank you for your help :)

Comment: ...so effectively, you needed to calculate the value of `y` **for each* value of `x` unsing the `func()` that you created.